# Where is the Cheshire Cat hiding?

Tags: disney-infinity-3.0

In the Toy Box Hub, the Cheshire Cat asked me to play hide and seek:

[image]

However, I've done multiple loops of the hub, and can't find him.  Where is he?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The location appears to be random, since I found him in a very different location to kenjara:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We found it in an alley on the upper floor of the Disney castle.

It could of course be random though.

Answer (score -2):

I also found him on the upper level of the castle. He gifts you with 1000 blue sparks :)

Comment: This is a "me too" answer. Why the flag was declined is a mistery to me.

Answer (score -2):

I found him on top of a cliff in the Halloween town area.

Answer (score -3):

I found the little brat on a Halloweentown rooftop, right next to the Race Track Start.